# Error when performing the authentication process by Azure Active Directory in test environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I'm implementing authentication by AD, for web project.
When I run locally the authentication run successfully, but when it is take to the test environment it generates the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'. ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden]'. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.<GetDocumentAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.<GetDocumentAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConn
```

**settings made in the portal**
[image]

[image]

**settings Startup.Auth**

```
public partial class Startup
{

    // Para obtener más información sobre cómo configurar la autenticación, visite https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864

    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
    private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
    private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
    private static string postLoginRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];


    public static readonly string Authority = aadInstance + tenantId;



    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        //https://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity-Custom-Database-and-OWIN/

        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = Authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                RedirectUri = postLoginRedirectUri
            });


        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie
        });
    }
}
```

**Controller SingIn and SingOut**

```
        public void SignIn()
        {
            // Enviar una solicitud de inicio de sesión a OpenID Connect.
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
        }

        public void SignOut()
        {
            if (true)
            {
                // Send an OpenID Connect sign-out request.
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Bottom line of exception says youare failing OpenId.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc

Answer (score 0):

- Please check if  proper internet connection is the issue while
  running on azure .
- The  error means the  application is not able to download the OpenId
  configuration document which has almost information that is  required
  for that app in order to sign-in such as the URLs , location of the
  public signing keys of service's .
- Please make sure these two lines are in order
  otherwise it will error:

  ```
   .UseAuthentication()
   .UseAuthorization()
  ```
- Also this error could be using the wrong `tenantId or authority` url in
  web.config file and `“Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"`
  To find out the error clearly. Set ***IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII =
  true*** in your `Startup.cs` .

  ```
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
  //
       IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
   //
   }
  ```
- And Please make sure to use the latest version (or to 4.7.2) of your
  dot-net framework as some of the  tasks may require updated / latest
  version of .NET framework to work properly.
- Check and use the protocol - TLS 1.2 for application as `TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.0  are depreciated.`
- In some cases packages maybe still defaulting to TLS 1.1 even after
  changing that when loading that metadata and it may take time to
  reflect the correct one.
- To resolve, try to add the following in Global.asax.cs which will
  allow the openid-configuration to be obtained as it is pointed to
  tls1.2 or above and also change the tls to 1.2 in portal also.

  ```
  protected void Application_Start()
   {
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3; //  allow TLSV1.2 and SSL3 only

  //or System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    //other code 
   }
  ```

**References:**

- [asp.net - Randomly occurring Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden]' - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73181530/randomly-occurring-unable-to-retrieve-document-from-pii-is-hidden/73194776#73194776)
- [Enable TLS 1.2 support as Azure AD TLS 1.0/1.1 is deprecated - Active Directory | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/enable-support-tls-environment?tabs=azure-monitor)